# How do I stop a wireless connection from connecting to an access point on boot?

Tags: wireless

I have been unable to find any where, sensible recommendations as to how to prevent my wireless card connecting to open wireless on boot.

Answer (score 2):

Open Network manager and either delete the profile for the wireless network in question or unselect the "connect automatically" option.

[image]